# Java Jsoup Issue: Unable to entire content of Ask.com

Tags: java, jsoup, user-agent

Just for fun I am testing how good JSOUP is at getting the content of pages and I am quite disappointed with its performance.

JSOUP seems to be having problems retrieving the source code out of ASK.com pages even though I can see the entire source code in Chrome without any issues.

I think JSOUP is either coming short here or I am doing something wrong. I want to clarify which is the case...

Can you please tell me why following doesn't work to get the entire document from the page:

```
    String url = "http://www.ask.com/answers/428870481/what-are-some-remedies-to-put-a-toddler-to-sleep";
    String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(ua).ignoreHttpErrors(true).timeout(30 * 1000).get();
```

If you check the content of the doc, it's cut off with "..." at the end. All that was loaded with only partial content, not the entire code. Why?

Comment: It seems to show all of the source text to me.

Comment: I've tried it on different PCs and it's not... have you actually compared it?

Comment: Actually you were right. It was just that I didn't see it fully. It was my eclipse 'variables' view which was cutting the content at 1000 characters. Thanks and sorry to bother.

Comment: Glad you've got it solved. Thanks for getting back to me about your solution.